# Is there a faster way to draw dynamic rectangles in VB?

Tags: vb.net, drawing, invalidation

I'm designing a program that will have some of the same features as MS Paint in VB.NET. The following code allows me to successfully click-and-drag to draw a selection rectangle on a picturebox, but it seems laggy (especially compared to MS Paint itself). Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
Public DrawCapture As Boolean = False
Public DrawCaptureOrigin As Point
Public DrawCaptureRectangle As Rectangle

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    DrawCapture = True
    DrawCaptureOrigin = e.Location
    DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rectangle(e.Location, New Point(1, 1))
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    Dim curX As Integer = e.Location.X, curY As Integer = e.Location.Y
    Dim dcoX As Integer = DrawCaptureOrigin.X, dcoY As Integer = DrawCaptureOrigin.Y
    If DrawCapture Then
        If curX < dcoX And curY < dcoY Then
            DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rectangle(curX, curY, dcoX - curX, dcoY - curY)
        ElseIf curX < dcoX Then
            DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rectangle(curX, dcoY, dcoX - curX, curY - dcoY)
        ElseIf curY < dcoY Then
            DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rectangle(dcoX, curY, curX - dcoX, dcoY - curY)
        Else
            DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rectangle(dcoX, dcoY, curX - dcoX, curY - dcoY)
        End If
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    DrawCapture = False
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If DrawCaptureRectangle.Width > 0 Then
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, DrawCaptureRectangle)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The likely speed/lag culprit is the `PictureBox`. IIrc, the `PictureBox` is just a `Bitmap` image that is wrapped to a control. To speed it up any decent amount, you would likely need to use a graphics API that is inherently faster. I.e. MDX, XNA, SlimDX, etc.

Comment: Thanks EBrown. I've never used any of them; is there one in particular that you might recommend for recreating MS Paint?

Comment: I would start by looking into something like SlimDX, SFML, or similar. I don't recall immediately, but I think they have controls you can drag and drop to a Windows Form/WPF Window.

Comment: If you dont care for `anti aliasing`(MS Paint doesnt use) you can use GDI instead of GDI+.

Comment: I specifically do not want anti-aliasing, because in the end, the project is for Minecraft (imagine SpriteCraft on crack with MS Paint built in). I'm not at all familiar with GDI/GDI+ or the differences between them. Not sure what you meant, but I'm interested to find out :)

Comment: I dont have an example right now. Propably later if someone doesnt provide one.

Comment: Works fine for me, but maybe this help : `e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed` and `e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce laggynes on my PC, so I not sure if this will help, but try to enable [Double Buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx). You can set it in the `Form` properties.

Comment: The Form was already double buffered, but I appreciate the suggestion. It's not super-laggy, but the difference between my code and MS Paint is noticeable, especially as the size of the picturebox increases.

Comment: It depends on the size. If the application is full screen you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

MS have made a thing called [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D), which is

> an easy-to-use Windows Runtime API for immediate mode 2D graphics rendering with GPU acceleration.

I have just tried it out for a first time. Here is rough comparison of the performance: `PictureBox` - 14.5% CPU usage and `CanvasControl` - 3.6% (4x times less; though almost 5x times more RAM usage).

So it seems that Win2D works faster and it actually is easy to use, but there is a catch. You can use it only with the Store App (for Windows or Windows Phone). Which means that it won't work on Windows 7. Take it or leave it. :)

---

I have 8-core CPU, so I assume that 100% loaded core should show up as 12.5% CPU usage.

[image: PictureBox CPU usage]
[image: CanvasControl CPU usage]

---

**How to create same application with Win2D**

1. Create Blank Store App.

   [image: Blank App (Windows)]
2. If this is your first Store App, then you will be asked to get Developer License; Just click `I Agree`.

   [image: Developer License]
3. Add `Win2D` NuGet package. (right click on your project in `Solution Explorer` >  `Manage NuGet Packages...`)
4. In `MainPage.xaml` add `CanvasControl`. Consider it as a replacement for `PictureBox`.

   ```
   <Page
       x:Class="Win2D_VBNET.MainPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:local="using:Win2D_VBNET"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
       mc:Ignorable="d">

       <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
           <canvas:CanvasControl ClearColor="White"
                                 Draw="CanvasControl_Draw"
                                 PointerPressed="CanvasControl_PointerPressed"
                                 PointerMoved="CanvasControl_PointerMoved"
                                 PointerReleased="CanvasControl_PointerReleased"/>
       </Grid>
   </Page>
   ```
5. Add all necessary event handlers in code-behind (`MainPage.xaml.vb`). Code is identical to what you had.

   ```
   Imports Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml
   Imports Windows.UI
   Imports Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas

   Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
       Inherits Page

       Public DrawCapture As Boolean = False
       Public DrawCaptureOrigin As Point
       Public DrawCaptureRectangle As Rect

       Private Sub CanvasControl_PointerPressed(sender As CanvasControl, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)
           Dim location As Point = e.GetCurrentPoint(Nothing).Position
           DrawCapture = True
           DrawCaptureOrigin = location
           DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rect(location, New Size(1, 1))
       End Sub

       Private Sub CanvasControl_PointerMoved(sender As CanvasControl, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)
           Dim location As Point = e.GetCurrentPoint(Nothing).Position
           Dim curX As Integer = location.X, curY As Integer = location.Y
           Dim dcoX As Integer = DrawCaptureOrigin.X, dcoY As Integer = DrawCaptureOrigin.Y
           If DrawCapture Then
               If curX < dcoX And curY < dcoY Then
                   DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rect(curX, curY, dcoX - curX, dcoY - curY)
               ElseIf curX < dcoX Then
                   DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rect(curX, dcoY, dcoX - curX, curY - dcoY)
               ElseIf curY < dcoY Then
                   DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rect(dcoX, curY, curX - dcoX, dcoY - curY)
               Else
                   DrawCaptureRectangle = New Rect(dcoX, dcoY, curX - dcoX, curY - dcoY)
               End If
           End If
           sender.Invalidate()
       End Sub

       Private Sub CanvasControl_PointerReleased(sender As CanvasControl, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)
           DrawCapture = False
           sender.Invalidate()
       End Sub

       Private Sub CanvasControl_Draw(sender As CanvasControl, args As CanvasDrawEventArgs)
           If DrawCaptureRectangle.Width > 0 Then
               args.DrawingSession.Antialiasing = CanvasAntialiasing.Aliased
               args.DrawingSession.DrawRectangle(DrawCaptureRectangle, Colors.Black)
           End If
       End Sub

   End Class
   ```